Excel Formula For Consecutive Values
I am trying to come up with a formula that puts an "OK" value in my Notes tab if the row has 2 or more consecutive 1 values. My rows have many more columns that just up to "N", this is just a screenshot I am using to try and make my question clearer.
I am admittedly a very novice excel user. Can anyone help me out here?


Two good answers but just to clarify, are two ones still regarded as consecutive if there is an empty cell between them like where you have 2,1,blank,1,2 ? It's good to add manually entered desired results in cases like these.

Thought I'd try a different approach.
TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,$J2:$N2) will stick all the cells together separated by a pipe character.
If two cells contain a 1 you'll get a 1|1 returned somewhere within the resulting text string, so you just need to find that.
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("1|1",TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,$J2:$N2))),"OK","")

The formula used
=LET(a,G4:M4,
b,OFFSET(a,0,1),
IF(SUM(IF((a=1)*(b=1),1,0))>0,"OK",""))


adapted to your  actual table
=LET(a,J8:N8,
b,OFFSET(a,0,1),
IF(SUM(IF((a=1)*(b=1),1,0))>0,"OK",""))


Another option using SUMPRODUCT:
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(J2:M2=1),--(K2:N2=1)),"OK","")



Lazy people like me really like this sort of solution!

I would use SCAN for anything that has the word "consecutive" in it:
Formula in F4 (can be filled down for the corresponding row):
=IF(OR(SCAN(0,G4:M4,LAMBDA(aggregated,current,(aggregated+current)*(current=1)))>=2),"OK","")


